# I am getting error by performing a JOIN operation in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to the programming world, I am learning Hadoop. While writing pig queries I am getting an output unexpected. The query I tried is

```
D = LOAD 'data1' AS (a:int,b:int);
S = LOAD 'data2' AS (c:int,d:int);
J = JOIN D by a, S by c;
DUMP J;
```

I am inserting outup and datasets. My requirement was only to get first coloumn of data 1 and first column of data 2(combine), but I got below

I am unable to insert the way I wanted.

o/p:

```
(1,2,1,3)
(4,3,4,9)
(4,3,4,6)
(4,2,4,9)
(4,2,4,6)
(8,3,8,6)
(8,3,8,9)
```

Data sets:

data 1:

```
1    2
4    2
8    3
4    3
7    2
8    4
```

data 2:

```
2    4
8    9
1    3
2    7
2    9
4    6
4    9
```

Comment: data in the datasets is not in a single row, i.e 1 and 2 will be in row 1 with /t space and then 4 and 2 will be in another row with /t space in between and so on. I am unable to insert in the way i wanted.

Comment: You're  joining 2 columns on 2 columns.... Why do you expect less than 4?

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement was only to get first column of data 1 and first column of data 2

Then you need another alias to extract the joined data.

```
J = JOIN D by a, S by c;
X = FOREACH J GENERATE $0, $2;
DUMP X;
```

However, that's going to result in the same numbers, for example, so I'm not sure that's what you want

```
1   1
4   4
4   4
```

Therefore, you may want to consider an outer join so you don't only get matching values

```
J = JOIN D by a LEFT OUTER, S by c;
```

I can't remember what results on the right side of the join, but probably NULL